# Printing a character between two % in C

Tags: c, printf

So I want to print in a 6 character field, with it being right aligned. I want to print a number, assigned to values[i], as a hexadecimal. So I print it using %x. And to print it in a 6 character field, I use %6x. But I want to prefix the number with an "x".
I want the output to be like  `x4000`, where the "x" prefixes the hexadecimal and is counted as one of the 6 characters. But I don't know how to combine it.

`printf("%6x", values[i]);`
I have no idea how to do it, please help.

Comment: Any reason why the output cant use `0x`? Since printf has built-in support for that even.

Answer (score 1):

First use `sprintf()` to create the `x4000` string. Then print that in a 6-character field with `printf()`.

```
char hex_string[10];
sprintf(hex_string, "x%x", values[i]);
printf("%6s", hex_string);
```